# Finding a table with columns X and X_FOO

Tags: sql, oracle

Suppose I have some tables with columns named *_FOO:

```
create table a(x number, x_foo number);
create table b(z_foo number);
```

How can I query USER_TAB_COLS to get (a) the list of columns where there both an X and X_FOO,

```
select table_name, short_col, foo_col from ... user_tab_cols ...

TABLE_NAME  SHORT_COL FOO_COL
----------  --------- -------
A           X         X_FOO
```

and (b) a list of X_FOO that have no corresponding X?

```
TABLE_NAME  FOO_COL
----------  -------
B           Z_FOO
```

This question is Oracle-specific in that the query would use USER_TAB_COLS, but I think the query join will be generic SQL?

Comment: Just to clarify, you're looking for any tables with columns with related names, X and X_FOO, where X can be anything and FOO is fixed; and without knowing which X you're looking for?

Comment: correct.  I'll update the question to spell that out.

Answer (score 2):

For the first one a simple join based on concatenation will do:

```
select utc1.table_name, utc1.column_name, utc2.column_name
from user_tab_columns utc1
join user_tab_columns utc2
on utc2.table_name = utc1.table_name
and utc2.column_name = utc1.column_name || '_FOO';

TABLE_NAME                     COLUMN_NAME                    COLUMN_NAME                  
------------------------------ ------------------------------ ------------------------------
A                              X                              X_FOO
```

For the second one you can start from anything called `'%_FOO'` and check that a column with the shorter name doesn't exist:

```
select utc1.table_name, utc1.column_name
from user_tab_columns utc1
where utc1.column_name like '%\_FOO' escape '\'
and not exists (
  select null
  from user_tab_columns utc2
  where utc2.table_name = utc1.table_name
  and utc2.column_name = substr(utc1.column_name, 1, length(utc1.column_name) -4)
);

TABLE_NAME                     COLUMN_NAME                  
------------------------------ ------------------------------
B                              Z_FOO
```

Or you could use an outer join if you prefer:

```
select utc2.table_name, utc2.column_name
from user_tab_columns utc1
right outer join user_tab_columns utc2
on utc2.table_name = utc1.table_name
and utc2.column_name = utc1.column_name || '_FOO'
where utc2.column_name like '%\_FOO' escape '\'
and utc1.column_name is null;

TABLE_NAME                     COLUMN_NAME                  
------------------------------ ------------------------------
B                              Z_FOO
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/e51a2d/3) with two outer join examples.

Answer (score 0):

Are you after something like this?

```
with sample_data as (select 'A' table_name, 'COL1' column_name from dual union all
                     select 'A' table_name, 'COL2' column_name from dual union all
                     select 'A' table_name, 'COL3' column_name from dual union all
                     select 'B' table_name, 'COL1' column_name from dual union all
                     select 'B' table_name, 'COL2' column_name from dual union all
                     select 'C' table_name, 'COL2' column_name from dual union all
                     select 'C' table_name, 'COL3' column_name from dual union all
                     select 'C' table_name, 'COL4' column_name from dual union all
                     select 'D' table_name, 'COL1' column_name from dual)
select distinct table_name,
                case when count(*) over (partition by table_name) = 2 then 'Both cols present'
                     when count(*) over (partition by table_name) = 1 and column_name = 'COL1' then 'COL1 present only'
                     when count(*) over (partition by table_name) = 1 and column_name = 'COL2' then 'COL2 present only'
                end cols_present
from   sample_data
where  column_name in ('COL1', 'COL2');


TABLE_NAME COLS_PRESENT     
---------- -----------------
A          Both cols present
B          Both cols present
C          COL2 present only
D          COL1 present only
```

Or perhaps something like this:

```
with sample_data as (select 'A' table_name, 'COL1' column_name from dual union all
                     select 'A' table_name, 'COL2' column_name from dual union all
                     select 'A' table_name, 'COL3' column_name from dual union all
                     select 'B' table_name, 'COL1' column_name from dual union all
                     select 'B' table_name, 'COL2' column_name from dual union all
                     select 'C' table_name, 'COL2' column_name from dual union all
                     select 'C' table_name, 'COL3' column_name from dual union all
                     select 'C' table_name, 'COL4' column_name from dual union all
                     select 'D' table_name, 'COL1' column_name from dual)
select   table_name,
         max(case when column_name = 'COL1' then column_name end) first_col,
         max(case when column_name = 'COL2' then column_name end) first_col
from     sample_data
where    column_name in ('COL1', 'COL2')
group by table_name;

TABLE_NAME FIRST_COL FIRST_COL_1
---------- --------- -----------
A          COL1      COL2       
B          COL1      COL2       
C                    COL2
D          COL1
```

(Obviously, I've just mocked up a subquery called sample_data that contains some data; you'd just query the user_tab_columns table directly.)